# Trouble Mapping a URL to my Java Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, url, web-applications

I need to fetch an object from a database by inputting a URL into the browser with the following pattern:

```
https://host.com/<something>?action=<actionName>&object=<node|interface>&selection=<list>&tenants=<list>
```

Where "something" is the method retrieving the paramaters and where the parameters consist of: action, object, selection, and tenants.

How would I go about establishing the pattern in the web.xml file to conform to a method that understands each of the above elements?

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>NewDynamicWebProject</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.test.package.NewDynamicWebProject</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NewDynamicWebProject</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/something/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

My class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class NewDynamicWebProject extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        something(req, resp);

    }

    protected void something(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String actionName = req.getParameter("action");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.print("<div>" + actionName + "</div>");

    }

}
```

How can I ensure that the parameters I pass into my URL make sense within the scope of my "something" method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dropped the "something" class and just did the following:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String actionName = req.getParameter("action");
    String objectType = req.getParameter("object");
    String selectionList = req.getParameter("selection");
    String tenantsList = req.getParameter("tenants");

    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.print("<div>" + actionName + " " + objectType + " " + selectionList + " " + tenantsList + "</div>");

}
```

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes. I was dramatically overthinking this... May as well leave it for reference.